# Animation Happening Immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I created a custom tableview cell that has pictures inside that the user can tap and highlight. I also want the highlight to be animated radially from the center until it covers the whole button. 
However, when the "button" (just the image view) is pressed, the animation happens instantly and is not animated. All of the code gets executed correctly, but just happens instantly instead of the correct duration. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

The part where there is the issue is under the function "presetTapped", and under the "if sender == self.flatTap" condition. The "animatedHighlightView" starts in the center of the superview with size 0,0. it then grows to the size of the super view. But instead of it animating, it happens instantly.

```
import UIKit

class PresetsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var flatButtonView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var antiSnoreButtonView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var zeroGravityButtonView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var flatButtonBackgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var antiSnoreButtonBackgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var zeroGravityButtonBackgroundView: UIView!

    var flatTap:UITapGestureRecognizer!
    var antiSnoreTap:UITapGestureRecognizer!
    var zeroGravityTap:UITapGestureRecognizer!
    var selectTap:UITapGestureRecognizer!
    var index:Int = -1

    var animatedHighlightView:UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.flatButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.antiSnoreButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.zeroGravityButtonView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        self.flatButtonBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.antiSnoreButtonBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.zeroGravityButtonBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        self.flatTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (self.presetTapped(_:)))
        self.flatButtonView.addGestureRecognizer(self.flatTap)
        self.antiSnoreTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (self.presetTapped(_:)))
        self.antiSnoreButtonView.addGestureRecognizer(self.antiSnoreTap)
        self.zeroGravityTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector (self.presetTapped(_:)))
        self.zeroGravityButtonView.addGestureRecognizer(self.zeroGravityTap)

        self.animatedHighlightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.origin.x + self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.width/2, y: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.origin.y + self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.height/2, width: 0, height: 0))
        self.animatedHighlightView.layer.cornerRadius = self.animatedHighlightView.frame.height/2
        self.animatedHighlightView.backgroundColor = kHighlightPrimary
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.animatedHighlightView)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func presetTapped(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let tb = self.superview as! DashboardTableView
        tb.selectedType = DashboardItems.Presets
        tb.reloadData()
        if sender == self.flatTap {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self.animatedHighlightView.frame = CGRect(x: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.origin.x, y: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.origin.y, width: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.width, height: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.height)
                self.animatedHighlightView.layer.cornerRadius = self.animatedHighlightView.frame.height/2
            }) { (complete) in
                self.antiSnoreButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor
                self.zeroGravityButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor
                tb.reloadData()
            }
            print("dashboard Flat tapped")
        } else if sender == self.antiSnoreTap {
            self.animatedHighlightView.frame = CGRect(x: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.origin.x + self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.width/2, y: self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.origin.y + self.flatButtonBackgroundView.frame.height/2, width: 0, height: 0)
            self.flatButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor
            self.antiSnoreButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kHighlightPrimary
            self.zeroGravityButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor
            tb.reloadData()
            print("dashboard Anti-Snore tapped")
        } else if sender == self.zeroGravityTap {
            self.flatButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor
            self.antiSnoreButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kBackgroundColor
            self.zeroGravityButtonBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kHighlightPrimary
            tb.reloadData()
            print("dashboard Zero Gravity tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you move the `UIView.animate` block into a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block?

Comment: I think you need a `self.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the `animations{}` block

Comment: Nope, both of those still make the animation happen instantly